# How to Run ffmpeg From Command Prompt

Tags: windows, mp4, avi

I am trying to get started using this [FFmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) "complete, cross-platform solution".

The home page has a line of code that says:

```
$ ffmpeg -i input.mp4 output.avi
```

When I plug this code into my command prompt, I get the following message:

```
'$' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are doing wrong is to copying the '$' as part of the command.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 output.avi
```

would do the trick.

Comment: That just gives me the same error but for ffmpeg. ffmpeg is not an exe, it is a .c file. Is that the problem? I navigated to the directory the file is in.

Comment: i just saw the "windows" tag. i think you are seeing the linux documentation

Comment: I found help here: https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/20495/how-do-i-set-up-and-use-ffmpeg-in-windows